# Unable to make redis on windows machine

Tags: node.js, redis, cygwin

I am trying to use `redis` in my `nodejs` project. I see that to build `redis` you need `make` command and `gcc`. I have instaled `cygwin` on my windows machine and then installed both `make` and `gcc`.

I downloaded `redis` from here https://redis.io/download and as per the instructions -

```
$ wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-3.2.8.tar.gz
$ tar xzf redis-3.2.8.tar.gz
$ cd redis-3.2.8
$ make
```

I am trying to do same, but facing some issues while building this. Here are the logs :-

```
D:\Node.JS\redis-3.2.8>make
cd src && make all
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/d/Node.JS/redis-3.2.8/src'
    CC adlist.o
    CC quicklist.o
    CC ae.o
In file included from ae.c:58:0:
ae_select.c: In function 'aeApiResize':
ae_select.c:52:37: warning: unused parameter 'eventLoop' [-Wunused-parameter]
 static int aeApiResize(aeEventLoop *eventLoop, int setsize) {
                                     ^~~~~~~~~
    CC anet.o
    CC dict.o
    CC server.o
    CC sds.o
    CC zmalloc.o
zmalloc.c: In function 'zmalloc_get_memory_size':
zmalloc.c:421:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-typ
e]
 }
 ^
    CC lzf_c.o
    CC lzf_d.o
    CC pqsort.o
    CC zipmap.o
    CC sha1.o
    CC ziplist.o
    CC release.o
    CC networking.o
    CC util.o
    CC object.o
    CC db.o
    CC replication.o
    CC rdb.o
    CC t_string.o
    CC t_list.o
    CC t_set.o
    CC t_zset.o
    CC t_hash.o
    CC config.o
    CC aof.o
    CC pubsub.o
    CC multi.o
    CC debug.o
debug.c: In function 'watchdogSignalHandler':
debug.c:1138:60: warning: unused parameter 'secret' [-Wunused-parameter]
 void watchdogSignalHandler(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *secret) {
                                                            ^~~~~~
    CC sort.o
    CC intset.o
    CC syncio.o
    CC cluster.o
    CC crc16.o
    CC endianconv.o
    CC slowlog.o
    CC scripting.o
    CC bio.o
    CC rio.o
    CC rand.o
    CC memtest.o
    CC crc64.o
    CC bitops.o
    CC sentinel.o
    CC notify.o
    CC setproctitle.o
    CC blocked.o
    CC hyperloglog.o
    CC latency.o
    CC sparkline.o
    CC redis-check-rdb.o
    CC geo.o
    LINK redis-server
cc: error: ../deps/hiredis/libhiredis.a: No such file or directory
cc: error: ../deps/lua/src/liblua.a: No such file or directory
cc: error: ../deps/geohash-int/geohash.o: No such file or directory
cc: error: ../deps/geohash-int/geohash_helper.o: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [Makefile:185: redis-server] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/d/Node.JS/redis-3.2.8/src'
make: *** [Makefile:6: all] Error 2

D:\Node.JS\redis-3.2.8>m
```

Can anyone help me what could be the issue ?

Comment: redis does not support windows. try [https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @FluffyNights suggested that `redis` does not support windows. I made it in working mode using https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis

Download releases from here https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases/download/win-3.2.100/Redis-x64-3.2.100.zip then extract this compressed file.

You will find `redis-server.exe` there, just execute it to start `redis` server. This has `redis` client also which you can use to execute its commands to save, get etc

Answer (score 1):

here the new redis 5 version compiled with info on how to do it 
https://github.com/meiry/redis5_compiled_for_windows10